# Display the name of the field in the graph's pop-up

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I configured the display of a graph when uploading a CSV. The user can choose the fields to configure the graph. However, I would like to replace the "get (input $)" that we see in the popup by the name of the field. Here is my function:

```
  #-------- REACTIVE DATA --------#
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$csv_chart)
    infile <- input$csv_chart
    if (is.null(infile))
      return(NULL)
    df <- read_csv(infile$datapath)
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'X', label = 'Field X:',
                      choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[1])
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'Y', label = 'Field Y:',
                      choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[2])
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'group', label = 'Group by:',
                      choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[3])
    return(df)
  })


  #-------- PLOT CHART --------#
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    ggplot(data()) +
      geom_line(mapping = aes(x = get(input$X), y = get(input$Y), color = as.character(get(input$group)))) +
      labs(x = input$X, y = input$Y, title = "Index Values")
  })
```

[image]

Comment: Could you give a fully reproducible code with dataset?